# ImportError: No module named Scientific_numerics_package_id

Tags: python, py2exe

I am trying to compile a python script for visualization of protein molecules using py2exe module. I've python2.7 running in win7 x64. When I try to execute the compiled file, it gives this error:-

```
C:\Python27\dist>visualn.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "visualn.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "MMTK\__init__.pyc", line 39, in <module>
  File "Scientific\Geometry\__init__.pyc", line 30, in <module>
  File "Scientific\Geometry\VectorModule.pyc", line 9, in <module>
  File "Scientific\N.pyc", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Scientific_numerics_package_id
```

Without compiling I can run the script successfully. I've already installed scientific,MMTK modules. I got somewhere in the internet that Scientific_numerics_package_id module is available in netCDF4, so I installed that also but no good.
Any idea about the error?

Answer (score 0):

You need the `python-netcdf` package.